# Calling a method within methods

Tags: java, methods, types

new to Java. I have an assignment due tonight but am stuck with what needs to be assigned within the `( )`. This is a verification of an email prefix and I am calling the prefix "example" from the method I used to get the prefix. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public static boolean isValidPrefixChar(char b) {
        return isAlphaNumeric(b) || b == '.' || b == '-' || b == '_';
```

This is where I am calling it:

```
public static boolean isValidPrefix(String str4) {
        getPrefix("example@mail.com");
        isValidPrefixChar(???);
```

Please and thanks!

Comment: Are you supposed to run your validation for every character in the result of `getPrefix()` call?

Comment: Yes, I am supposed to validation for every character.

Comment: I see your point now concerning iteration, with an example lower down. Wasn't executing this properly. Will be working on this more. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

To directly answer your question, identify the `char` value of the first character of your string. Call [`String#charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)). Unfortunately, that method uses annoying zero-based index counting. So the first character is counterintuitively zero rather than one.

```
isValidPrefixChar( prefix.charAt( 0 ) );
```

But… Better to avoid `char` type. Pass a code point number:

```
isValidPrefixChar( prefix.codePointAt( 0 ) ); // Pass code point number assigned to the first (index zero) character of your input string.
```

## `char` is obsolete

The `char` type has been legacy since Java 2. As a 16-bit value it is physically incapable of representing most characters. Instead use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

## Code points

Every known character has been assigned a specific permanent number as an identifier. This number is known as a [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point).

- `.` = FULL STOP = 46 decimal
- `-` = HYPHEN-MINUS = 45 decimal
- `_` = LOW LINE = 95 decimal

Your examination of a single character would take an `int` argument, as the code point.

```java
public static boolean isValidPrefixCharacter ( int codePoint )
{
    if ( ! Character.isValidCodePoint( codePoint ) ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Invalid code point number passed." ); }
    return
            Character.isLetterOrDigit( codePoint )
                    || codePoint == ".".codePointAt( 0 )  // Annoying zero-based index counting.
                    || codePoint == "-".codePointAt( 0 )
                    || codePoint == "_".codePointAt( 0 )
            ;
}
```

I assume the `.codePointAt` calls will be [inlined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) by the compiler, but I do not know for sure.

That method would be called from another method like this.

```java
public static boolean isValidPrefix ( String possibleEmailAddress )
{
    Objects.requireNonNull( possibleEmailAddress );
    if ( possibleEmailAddress.isBlank() ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Possible email address must have some not text, not empty string." ); }
    int codePointOfFirstCharacter = possibleEmailAddress.codePointAt( 0 );   // Annoying zero-based index counting.
    boolean isPrefixValid = isValidPrefixCharacter( codePointOfFirstCharacter );
    return isPrefixValid;
}
```

Example harness code.

```java
boolean isValid = App8.isValidPrefix( "example@example.com" );
System.out.println( "isValid = " + isValid );

isValid = App8.isValidPrefix( "example@example.com" );
System.out.println( "isValid = " + isValid );
```

When run.

```
isValid = true
isValid = false
```

Later you clarified that you want to examine every character, not just the first. In that case, modify that one method.

```java
public static boolean isValidPrefix ( String possibleEmailAddress )
{
    Objects.requireNonNull( possibleEmailAddress );
    if ( possibleEmailAddress.isEmpty() ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Possible email address must have some not text, not empty string." ); }
    String emailPrefix = possibleEmailAddress.split( "@" )[ 0 ];  // Annoying zero-based index counting.
    int[] codePoints = emailPrefix.codePoints().toArray();
    for ( int codePoint : codePoints )
    {
        boolean isCharacterValid = isValidPrefixCharacter( codePoint );
        if ( ! isCharacterValid ) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And expand our tests.

```
boolean isValid = App8.isValidPrefix( "example@example.com" );
System.out.println( "isValid = " + isValid );

isValid = App8.isValidPrefix( "example@example.com" );
System.out.println( "isValid = " + isValid );

isValid = App8.isValidPrefix( "example@example.com" );
System.out.println( "isValid = " + isValid );
```

When run.

```
isValid = true
isValid = false
isValid = false
```

Comment: Unfortunately this well beyond my capacities right now, but I do appreciate it. Will read up on this.

Comment: @JohnBossi When you are ready… [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: Was looking at this yesterday with a friend and am starting to understand what you are saying here. Definitely something I will be spending time looking at. Thank you.

Comment: Will have a read this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do iterate over prefix, and check every character of prefix if its valid:

```
public static boolean isValidPrefixChar(char b) { 
    return isAlphaNumeric(b) || b == '.' || b == '-' || b == '_';
}

public static boolean isValidPrefix(String str4) {
    String s = getPrefix("example@mail.com");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length; i++){
        if(!isValidPrefixChar(s.charAt(i)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It's wasteful to keep iterating once you find an invalid character. Just return false.

Comment: @shmosel thank you for the comment, i change it. I write it fast

Comment: The problem is I am required to call the method in. Sorry, wasn't clear there.

Comment: I actually have the for loop below waiting, but I just don't understand what to put inot the ( ) when I call this method in.

Comment: Completely missed your point here. My bad. would have saved me a lot of eye strain had I just read this line. Thanks for trying to help! Will be applying this all the same. Not done until it works right.